# Perrmision denied after /etc/profile while installing Java

Tags: java, etc

I am trying to install Java. I have to reload my system wide `PATH` from `/etc/profile` by typing the following command:

```
/etc/profile
```

And then I get the error:

```
bash: /etc/profile: permission denied
```

Why do I get this and how do I fix it?
Can I fix it opening another Terminal window? Will my installation complete if i reboot computer? (if it is needed to fix this problem)

Answer (score 3):

The `/etc/profile` file is not executable - to reload its configuration in the current shell you need to *source* it - either

```
. /etc/profile
```

(note the dot and space ahead of the file name) or

```
source /etc/profile
```